# Sending HTTP messages to a specific client connection/web session using cURL/NodeJs scripts with SSEs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, server-sent-events

Hi so first I apologize if my query may seem unclear, it’s first trying to do what I’m doing and I haven’t full idea around the intricacies and lingo lol.

So basically I’m running a NodeJs web server with React handling my front end. I’ve got Express to help manipulate user sessions and I just came by Server-Sent-Events as a way to send one-way messages(which is what I need to do). So far I’m able to send updates and messages via cURL on the terminal and running JS scripts, however these updates/messages go to every active client session but I want/need to be able to send these messages to specific active client sessions/connections.

Example: 5 client connections are established (session IDs A,B,C,D,E), now I want to send an alert message to session E only and manually.

I’m still green with NodeJs/Express and the concept of SSEs however I’m learning as I go for this pet project.

Send help

Answer (score 0):

What you want is how SSE works. It is a dedicated connection between a client and a server process.

> however these updates/messages go to every active client session

If that is what you see then your node script is running the exact same code for each client.

I think your question might be higher up - how to organize the data messaging? That is too big a topic for a single StackOverflow question, because it will depend on so many factors specific to your use case.

But one way would be to have an SQL database, with one record for each user. The node script polls that database table and if the record for the current user changes, it sends the new data to them. Then to send data to user E, you just edit the database record for user E.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Can I use Redis as the database system as opposed to an SQL database in this solution?

Comment: @EmmanuelBatse Yes. Any database system you can poll in this way could be used. (And the same idea works with a database that gives you push notifications.)